# What does related_name do?

Tags: django

In the Django documentation about `related_name` it says the following:

> The name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one. It’s also the default value for `related_query_name` (the name to use for the reverse filter name from the target model). See the related objects documentation for a full explanation and example. Note that you must set this value when defining relations on abstract models; and when you do so some special syntax is available.
>
> If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set related_name to '+' or end it with '+'.

I didn't understand it clearly. If somebody would please explain it a bit more, it would help me a lot.

Comment: This seems a bit broad. What exactly about this - and the linked documentation - don't you understand?

Comment: Why it is used and where it is used and what's about the '+' sign?

Comment: But those are the things that are explicitly explained in the paragraphs you quote.

Comment: Actually I'm new in django and it is hard to understand(probably because I'm dumb). So, I thought if I asked here some expertise would break the paragraph a bit and explain a bit more about "relation from the related object back to this one" and "+" sign.

Comment: That's the name you need to call from a related object in order to get it's parent-related model object(s)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you create a foreign key, you are linking two models together. The model with the `ForeignKey()` field uses the field name to look up the other model. It also implicitly adds a member to the linked model referring back to this one.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ... fields ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    # ... fields ...
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name=???)
```

There are three possible scenarios here:

#### 1. Don't specify `related_name`

If you don't specify a name, django will create one by default for you.

```
some_post = Post.objects.get(id=12345)
comments = some_post.comment_set.all()
```

The default name is the relation's name + `_set`.

#### 2. Specify a custom value

Usually you want to specify something to make it more natural. For example, `related_name="comments"`.

```
some_post = Post.objects.get(id=12345)
comments = some_post.comments.all()
```

#### 3. Prevent the reverse reference from being created

Sometimes you don't want to add the reference to the foreign model, so use `related_name="+"` to not create it.

```
some_post = Post.objects.get(id=12345)
comments = some_post.comment_set.all() # <-- error, no way to access directly
```

---

`related_query_name` is basically the same idea, but when using `filter()` on a queryset:

```
posts_by_user = Post.objects.filter(comments__user__id=123)
```

But to be honest I've never used this since the `related_name` value is used by default.

Answer (score 16):

1. If in a model you have a `ForeignKey` field (this means you point through this field to other model):

   ```
   class Author(models.Model):
       name = ......
       email = .....

   class Article(models.Model):
       author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
       title= ....
       body = ....
   ```

   if you specify `related_name` on this field

   ```
   class Article(modles.Model):
       author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='articles')
   ```

   you give a name to the attribute that you can use for the relation (named **reverse realationship**) from the related object back to this one (from `Author` to `Article`). After defining this you can retrieve the articles of an user like so:

   ```
   author.articles.all()
   ```
2. If you don't define a `related_name` attribute, Django will use the lowercase name of the model followed by `_set` (that is, in our case, `article_set`) to name the relationship from the related object back to this one, so you would have to retrieve all articles of an user like so:

   ```
   author.article_set.all()
   ```
3. If you don't want to be possible a reverse relationship (from the model to which points your `ForeignKey` filed to this model (the model in which the `ForeignKey` field is defined) you can set

   ```
   class Author(models.Model):
       author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
   ```