# SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am building a project to place an order. When I run makemigrations command then it gives an error of

> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues and I have deleted the migration file from migrations

Traceback:

> order.Order.price: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Order.price' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Order.product'.
>
> ```
>   HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Order.price' or 'Order.product'.
> ```
>
> order.Order.product: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Order.product' clashes with reverse accessor for
> 'Order.price'.
>
> ```
>     HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Order.product' or 'Order.price'.
> ```

My `models.py` is as follows:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company + self.product + self.price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `related_name` like:

```
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product')
    price = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='price')
```

`related_name` is used to link the models. Especially, when you have more than `1` model linking to another model. It is compulsary as in your case. [See_this_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44161769/10860596O) to understand properly about use of `related_name`.

Comment: is related_name a url's name?

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "order_order" already exists

Comment: Try this command: ```python manage.py migrate --fake <appname>```

Comment: Unknown command: '--fake'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Comment: Please make sure you have typed your <appname>... and **kept it** in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

Comment: Are you sure... plz review once again... each and every spelling

Comment: Can you write exactly what did you write, in console including your app name.

Comment: Yes, it will work properly. But, don't forget to check the link I shared in the post to understand the concept of it.

Comment: it is working correctly but giving the same  drop-down result of products instead of Prices

Comment: You have completed the `db` related error. But, now you are having problem with `views` or `template`. Do some research. If still could not figure that out. SO is here. Chill!!!

Answer (score 1):

Both your foreign keys referrencing same model `Product` without defining different related names:

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

price = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If that's not an error then simply add different [related names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: Sir it has given me this error now after makemigrations

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "order_order" already exists

Comment: You need to rollback migrations first or fake it as previous commenter adviced, because tables are already created in your DB.

Comment: so how to roll back my migrations? I mean any command for it or I have to delete database manually?