# Django Rest Framework, nested serializers, inner serializer not visible in outer serializer

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use nested serializers in my app. I followed documentation seen on DRF website but it seems there is a problem with inner serializer visibility. The error message:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `produkty` on serializer `ZamowieniaSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Zamowienie` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Zamowienie' object has no attribute 'produkty'.
```

models.py

```
class Zamowienie(models.Model):
    kontrahent = models.ForeignKey(Kontrahent, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    my_id = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    data_zal = models.DateTimeField()
    data_realizacji = models.DateField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="0")
    komentarz = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, default="")
    uwagi = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=False, default="")
    zam_knt_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-data_zal']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Zamowienia'

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.my_id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        licznik = Zamowienie.objects.filter(Q(kontrahent=self.kontrahent) &
                                            Q(timestamp__year=timezone.now().year)).count() + 1
        self.my_id = str(licznik) + "/" + self.kontrahent.nazwa + "/" + str(timezone.now().year)
        self.zam_knt_id = self.kontrahent.zam_knt_id
        super(Zamowienie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Produkt(models.Model):
    zamowienie = models.ForeignKey(Zamowienie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ean = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=False, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    kolor_frontu = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False, blank=True)
    kolor_korpusu = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False, blank=True)
    kolor_blatu = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False, blank=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    zam_twrid = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=False, blank=True)
    ilosc = models.IntegerField(unique=False, default=0)
    ilosc_do_odebrania = models.IntegerField(unique=False, default=0)
    komentarz = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    waga = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, blank=True, default=0)
    dlugosc = models.DecimalField(unique=False, blank=True, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    szerokosc = models.DecimalField(unique=False, blank=True, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    zakonczenie = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ZAKONCZENIE_CHOICES, blank=True)
    wykonczenie = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=WYKONCZENIE_CHOICES, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-update_time']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Produkty'

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.model) + ' ' + str(self.symbol) + ' ' + str(self.ean)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Zamowienie, Produkt


class ProduktySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Produkt
        fields = ['ean', 'model', 'kolor_frontu', 'kolor_korpusu', 'kolor_blatu', 'zam_twrid', 'ilosc',
                  'komentarz', 'zakonczenie', 'wykonczenie']


class ZamowieniaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    produkty = ProduktySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Zamowienie
        fields = ['data_zal', 'data_realizacji', 'status', 'komentarz', 'uwagi', 'produkty']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        produkty_dane = validated_data.pop('produkty')
        zamowienie = Zamowienie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for produkt in produkty_dane:
            Produkt.objects.create(zamowienie=zamowienie, **produkt)
        return zamowienie
```

views.py

```
class ZamowienieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ZamowieniaSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        zamowienia = Zamowienie.objects.filter(kontrahent=user)
        return zamowienia
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'zam', views.ZamowienieViewSet, basename='Zamowienie')


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I skipped most of the code that does not matter to DRF. I didn't notice any mistake compared to documentation. Any idea what did I do wrong?

It looks like the problem dissapears when I add `produkty = ProduktySerializer(many=True, write_only=True)` to outer serializer definition (specifically `write_only=True` statement). Why does it work only that way?

Answer (score 0):

The error said it all:

> 'Zamowienie' object has no attribute 'produkty'

If you want `produkty` to be available in `Zamowienie` model, you need to set a `related_name` in a `ForeignKey` in `Produkty` model like this:

```py
zamowienie = models.ForeignKey(Zamowienie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='produkty')
```

This way, you can access your produkty list from zamowienie and your serializer should work again without using `write_only=True`.

Last, about why `write_only=True` did the trick, it's because when you're fetching the data (`read`), you told Django to not looking for `produkty` from `Zamowienie` model. Therefore, only when creating (`write`) was using `produkty` which you already handled it in `create()`.

P.S. the related name should be plural but I'm not sure what it should be so I didn't change it to :)

Ref: [What does related_name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160983/what-does-related-name-do)